# Ubuntu 17.10 printing "^@" to all ttys

Tags: ubuntu, tty

I have the following problem:

I have(apparently) installed a faulty graphics driver and am caught in a login loop. I know how I can fix this issue, but I cannot login through any of the ttys that I can reach with the `Ctrl+Alt+Fx` combination, because the system keeps writing a `^@` character to all of the virtual terminals, making all my login attempts fail. I have, however, never had these characters printed into any terminal emulator.

Does anyone know what this character means and how I could fix my problem?

Comment: `^@` generally indicates a null (0x0) character, so it looks as though you are receiving streams of nulls. Have you tried recovery mode?

Comment: @AFH I did just now, and when I drop to the root shell I can access the system. Thanks!

Comment: Although I would still like to know why my system is streaming null chars to all of the virtual terminals

Comment: Didn't you say it yourself: wrong graphics driver?

Comment: No, the graphics driver was what sent me into the login loop. The stream of nulls just kept me from logging in through the ttys as I would normally do to resolve an issue like this. I still have no idea what prints these characters to stdout(which it still does even after resolving the login loop issue)

Comment: You'll need to look at your start-up files `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` and any files they invoke. If you can start `bash --noprofile`, you can see if this makes a difference. Or do the nulls appear at the log-in prompt?

Comment: They already appear at the tty login prompt. Also my login shell is zsh if that changes anything.

Comment: If it happens before you log in, then the log-in shell is not relevant, though the start-up files are of course different.